# How can I solve segment error while giving values greater than 10000000 in this c++ programm?

Tags: c++

How can I solve segment error while giving values greater than 10000000 in this c++ programm?
I was trying the practice projects in projecteuler.net and I got this error
Please help

It is showing error in this portion of the code `uint64_t prime[max];`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<uint64_t> factors(uint64_t j)
{
    vector<uint64_t> facs;

    uint64_t count = 0, i = 2;

    for (i = 1; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (j % i == 0)
        {
            facs.push_back(i);
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    return facs;
}

uint64_t prime(uint64_t ml)
{
    uint64_t max = ml;

    uint64_t prime[max];
    vector<uint64_t> a = factors(ml);
    vector<uint64_t> max_factors;
    unordered_set<uint64_t> p;

    uint64_t max_prime_factor;
    uint64_t i, j;

    prime[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < max; i++)
    {
        prime[i] = i;
    }
    for (i = 4; i < max; i += 2)
    {
        prime[i] = 2;
    }

    for (i = 3; i * i < max; i++)
    {
        if (prime[i] == i)
        {
            for (j = i * i; j < max; j += i)
            {
                if (prime[j] == j)
                {
                    prime[j] = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i : prime)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            p.insert(i);
        }
    }

    for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); ++i)
    {
        for (uint64_t k : p)
        {
            if (*i == k)
            {
                max_factors.push_back(*i);
            }
        }
    }

    max_prime_factor = *max_element(max_factors.begin(), max_factors.end());

    return max_prime_factor;
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t j;

    cout << "Enter the number to find the largest prime factor : ";
    cin >> j;

    cout << prime(j);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just replace `uint64_t prime[max];` with `std::vector`.

Comment: "_I got this error_" isn't a very good description of the error you got. Copy/paste the error message in full.

Comment: this might be helpful: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ODZ2TL4VgjJv6b0c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable-length array like

```
    uint64_t prime[max];
```

is not supported in C++ and it has a risk of causing stack overflow when trying to allocate a large size.

You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

```
    std::vector<uint64_t> prime(max);
```